# Checkbox status in winform while code is in DLL

Tags: vb.net

I have been given a task to export code into a DLL to hide sensitive code from other developers on the project. This is a winform VB.net project and uses checkboxes extensively. Much of this sensitive code contains references like this.

If Form1.CheckBox102.Checked = False then

The problem is that placing this code into the DLL breaks those references. I'm under the impression that this is because you cant reference the form of the main exe from the DLL.

So this brings me to the question, what is one to do? Is there a way to 'establish' some kind of link between the two? Or is it just a matter of having those references passed in the code when accessing the classes of the DLL?

Comment: Honesty, sounds messy to me but that aside yes you will need to pass form references into the DLL, you will also need to ad a reference to WinForms in your dll.  That said though, developers will need to be able to add this DLL as a reference to their product meaning that it will be to some degree at least visible to them.   However, maybe trying to be a little funny here, but if _Form1.CheckBox102_ as a naming convention is any indication of the code you're protecting, I feel confident enough is sufficiently obfuscated already

Comment: The DLL should define some sort of model class that can be passed in and out and the application code can set `Boolean` properties based on the `CheckBoxes`, maybe via data-binding. The DLL then only cares about that model and its properties and doesn't even have to know that any forms or `CheckBoxes` even exist.

Comment: You will need create an interface on the DLL where you can map references to the checkboxes from the main app. I should warn you that most .NET developers know about and own a free copy of https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/, so unless you're running your code through a good obfuscator prior to deployment the dll is not a good way of hiding sensitive code.